SwiftUI TextField with vertical axis doesn't limit lines or characters
I'm experiencing issues with a TextField on the vertical axis in SwiftUI. I'm unable to limit the number of lines or characters. Everything works fine when the vertical axis parameter is removed. Here's my code:
@State private var text = ""

List{
   Section {
     TextField("placeholder", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
     .linelimit(3)
   }
}

I also tried to limit characters by going:
@State var textLimit: Int = 10

List{
   Section {
     TextField("placeholder", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
     .onChange(of: text){
          text = String(text.prefix(titleLimit))
     }
   }
}

But nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

The line limit seems to work fine for me

Note that a TexField isn't limited to the value given as argument to lineLimit if that is what you expect. The documentation says "When the text of such views occupies more space than the provided limit, a Text view truncates its content while a TextField becomes scrollable."

Unfortunately the documentation is different depending on which constructor you look up so it's easy to miss the above.

@JoakimDanielson thanks for the feedback. Point is that I can't limit its character limit too! It just keeps scrolling over and over. And the problem seems to disappear when I remove the "vertical axis" parameter from it. Really annoying.
